# Cisco CPU utilization threshold violation traps

Tags: cisco, snmp, cpu

I enabled SNMP and Traps on a cisco router and I used `snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold` command in configuration mode.

I configured **LinkUp-Down** Traps with `snmp-server enable traps snmp linkup linkdown` and this is send traps to 172.16.98.28/24 host and after enable **cpu threshold**, no traps send to 172.16.98.28/24 host.
What's wrong?

My Device: c3640 IOS 12.4

Comment: You really need to give more detail. You should edit your question to include the device model and configuration. Are you running SNMP software on the host at `172.16.98.28`?

Comment: Can you clarify the question as well please? Are you saying that LinkUp/Down traps were working fine but you no longer see LinkUp/Down traps (when there is a linkUp/down event) after enabling traps for CPU threshold? Or that you are not seeing CPU threshold traps (when CPU is high)? Or both?

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm sorry, my device is c3640. Yes, I used **iReasoning MIB Browser** on the host at 172.16.98.28 and c3640 has response to my snmp request. How to enable **CPU Utilization Traps**?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up snmptraps and snmp queries. You can't use a MIB browser to request traps, you'll need a trap receiver to collect them.

Comment: @hertitu LinkUp/Down traps has Worked but after typing this command `snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold`, I have not received trap about CPU.

Comment: @TeunVink No, **iReasoning MIB Browser** have a [Trap Receiver](http://www.ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml).

Comment: Don't mention 'snmp rqeuests' then, it makes it only more confusing. Did you configure a threshold? (something like `process cpu threshold type total rising 80 interval 5`) and verify that when testing the CPU load actually was high?

Comment: @TeunVink `process cpu threshold type total rising 80 interval 5` Opps, It's worked and i get **CPU threshold Trap**. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Step 1 :** `snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold`
- **Step 2 :** `process cpu threshold type total rising 80 interval 5`

In **Step 1** i'm enabled **CPU Threshold Trap** and in **Step 2** i'm enabled **CPU Threshold** for each 5 second if CPU percent is 80.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.